# Multiple 'belongsTo' relationships on thinky model

Tags: orm, relationship, rethinkdb, thinky

I have two models, User and Capture, where a Capture can be related to multiple users: it is owned, claimed, and processed all by three different users.

```
User = thinky.createModel 'User',
    id:           String
    displayName:  String
    email:        String

Capture = thinky.createModel 'Capture',
    id: String
    ownerID: String
    processedByID: String
    claimedByID: String
    created: Date
    updated: Date

Capture.belongsTo User.model, 'owner', 'ownerID', 'id'
Capture.belongsTo User.model, 'processedBy', 'processedByID', 'id'
Capture.belongsTo User.model, 'claimedBy', 'claimedByID', 'id'
```

The owner relationship works, but I cannot get the processedBy and claimedBy relationships to work. I'm querying with `.getJoin()`, and  Thinky has created the secondary indexes on my tables (so it at least knows about the relationships)

What am I doing wrong? How can I get the nested objects to return in my queries?

Answer (score 3):

That's because thinky will join another model once by default (to avoid circular references).
You must be explicit on the links you want to fetch:

```
 Capture.getJoin({owner: true, processedBy: true, claimedBy: true}).run()
```